# applescript getElementsByName in Chrome

Tags: applescript, google-chrome, javascript

I need to fill up a text field and click on a button on Google Chrome

Here is my script for safari.

```
tell application "Safari"

## tell window 1 of application "Safari" to set current tab to tab 1
-- Last Name
do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('0.7.7.7.7.7.5')[0].value=" & quoted form of theProfil & "" in tab 1 of window 1
-- search
delay 0.1
do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('0.7.7.7.7.1.7')[0].click();" in tab 1 of window 1
```

How can I use this (getElementsByName) with Chrome ?

cheers.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Chrome is scriptable through the Chromium suite—the `execute` method is what you're looking for. Here is an example of your code, re-written for Chrome:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    execute front window's active tab javascript  "document.getElementsByName('0.7.7.7.7.7.5')[0].value=" & quoted form of theProfil & ""
    delay 0.1
    execute front window's active tab javascript "document.getElementsByName('0.7.7.7.7.1.7')[0].click();"
end tell
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135609/can-applescript-access-browser-tabs-and-execute-javascript-in-them) on Stack Overflow for reference, or consult the Google Chrome AppleScript dictionary (in Script Editor, click `File` > `Open Dictionary…` and choose Google Chrome).

Comment: that's perfect, I was looking for this for ages, thank you